# Installing Tensorflow in M1 Mac

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, apple-m1

I followed this tutorial, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ykCY_tJbhNw to install tensorflow in a mac (M1 processor). However when I import tensrflow I get the following error. Any ideas what it might be?

The steps include,

- installing brew (was alreadyy installed)
- install conda (was already installed)
- installing miniforge
- download tensorflow-macos from github page
- `conda activate mlEnv`
- `/Users/imantha/Software/tensorflow_macos/install_venv.sh -p`
- When prompted to input the path : `/Users/imantha/Software/anaconda3/envs/mlEnv/`
- and select yes to install tensorflow
- tensorflow was successfully installed and when typed `conda list`, the package is listed.

However when I start python session in the shell and type `import tensorflow as tf`, I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/imantha/Software/anaconda3/envs/mlEnv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 64, in <module>
from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/imantha/Software/anaconda3/envs/mlEnv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so, 6): no suitable image found.  Did find:
/Users/imantha/Software/anaconda3/envs/mlEnv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
/Users/imantha/Software/anaconda3/envs/mlEnv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/Users/imantha/Software/anaconda3/envs/mlEnv/lib/python3.8/site- 
packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
File "/Users/imantha/Software/anaconda3/envs/mlEnv/lib/python3.8/site- 
packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 39, in <module>
from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow as _pywrap_tensorflow
File "/Users/imantha/Software/anaconda3/envs/mlEnv/lib/python3.8/site- 
packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 83, in <module>
raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/imantha/Software/anaconda3/envs/mlEnv/lib/python3.8/site- 
packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 64, in <module>
from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
ImportError: 
dlopen(/Users/imantha/Software/anaconda3/envs/mlEnv/lib/python3.8/site- 
packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so, 6): no suitable image 
found.  Did find:
/Users/imantha/Software/anaconda3/envs/mlEnv/lib/python3.8/site- 
packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so: mach-o, but wrong 
 architecture
/Users/imantha/Software/anaconda3/envs/mlEnv/lib/python3.8/site- 
packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so: mach-o, but wrong 
architecture


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

Answer (score 2):

There are quite a few things to do in order to install TensorFlow on the Macbook M1 chip:

- First, install `Python 3.8.9` (I have tried on this version, not sure about any other versions)
- Go to your project dir
- install hdf5 by running `brew install hdf5` if you do not have brew, you can download it here: https://brew.sh/
- Above `hdf5` install will spit out its location: use it and run:
  `export HDF5_DIR=<hdf5_location>` for version 1.13.0 (my case) the following:

```
export HDF5_DIR=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/hdf5/1.13.0
```

- create a virtual environment using `virtualenv venv` (choose whatever method for creating virtual environment or do not create virtual environment, it's fine. To install `virtualenv`, run `pip3 install virtualenv`)
- (Skip this if not using virtual environment) Activate virtual environment by running: `source venv/bin/activate`
- Now, we have everything require to install Tensorflow on mac with M1 chip including GPU version
- To install Tensorflow and related libs, run following:
  (If using virtual env, run following)

```
venv/bin/pip install --no-binary=h5py h5py
venv/bin/pip install tensorflow-macos
venv/bin/pip install tensorflow-metal
```

Not using virtual env, run following:

```
pip3 install --no-binary=h5py h5py
pip3 install tensorflow-macos
pip3 install tensorflow-metal
```

- Now, your TensorFlow installation has been completed!
- Try it out:

```
import tensorflow as tf

print("TF version:", tf.__version__)
print("Number GPUs Available: ", len(tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')))
print("Number CPUs Available: ", len(tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('CPU')))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Build Tensorflow from source by following the instructions mentioned [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source).
See this [comment](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/44751#issuecomment-764841687).

OR,

Try the workaround mentioned [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/48726#issuecomment-826850187).

Answer (score 0):

The below way is the simplest and efficient way from which we can install tensorflow in Mac M1

NOTE: Mac M1 has ARM64 arch not X86_64 so we need to be very careful while downloading packages. Anaconda is available for Mac M1 users : https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2022.05-MacOSX-arm64.sh

Following are the steps to victory:

1. Download Anaconda from above link
2. create virtual env ( Optional )
3. pip install tensorflow-macos

Thats it!

Reference video link which may be useful : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5DgWvU0p2bk

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use an Anaconda distribution, you might want to consider Miniconda3. Currently, I'm not sure whether it's possible to install TensorFlow using Anaconda.

- Download Miniconda3 using [this](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html) link. Both the `.bash` and the `.pkg` files should do - choose one of them. However, for M1, only the `.bash` file seem to have worked, while for M2 both worked.
- If you used the `.bash` file above, then do the following to start the installation:

```bash
chmod +x ~/Downloads/Miniforge3-MacOSX-arm64.sh
sh ~/Downloads/Miniforge3-MacOSX-arm64.sh
```

- Create a conda environment with Python 3.9: `conda create -n tf_env python=3.9` (latest Python version didn't work as I'm writing this).
- Install TensorFlow and dependencies:

```bash
conda install -c apple tensorflow-deps
python -m pip install tensorflow-macos
python -m pip install tensorflow-metal
```

- At this point, you should make sure that the Numpy version is up to date to not run into errors when importing TensorFlow. I used version 1.23.3. `python -m pip install numpy --upgrade`.
- Install jupyter notebook using `conda install notebook`.
- If everything has been installed without errors, running the following code in a jupyter notebook should correctly import TensorFlow and print out the version as well as verifying the presence of a GPU.

```py
import tensorflow as tf

gpu = len(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')) > 0
print(f"TensorFlow Version: {tf.__version__}")
print("GPU is", "available" if gpu else "NOT available")
```