# Error When Importing TensorFlow on Mac M1 Pro. MacOs version 13.0. Python 3.10

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, miniconda

**Things I did / run:
**

- Downloaded MiniConda
- Created Virtual env
- Inside env, installed ipykernel
- created new kernel for use in jupyter

**TensorFlow Installation following: https://developer.apple.com/metal/tensorflow-plugin/
**

1. conda install -c apple tensorflow-deps
2. python -m pip install tensorflow-macos
3. python -m pip install tensorflow-metal

- Then I created a jupyter lab notebook, selected previously created kernel, and did: import tensorflow as tf, and it gave this error:

```
NotFoundError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 1
----> 1 import tensorflow as tf

File ~/opt/miniconda3/envs/ImageClassification/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py:443
    441 _plugin_dir = _os.path.join(_s, 'tensorflow-plugins')
    442 if _os.path.exists(_plugin_dir):
--> 443   _ll.load_library(_plugin_dir)
    444   # Load Pluggable Device Library
    445   _ll.load_pluggable_device_library(_plugin_dir)

File ~/opt/miniconda3/envs/ImageClassification/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/load_library.py:151, in load_library(library_location)
    148     kernel_libraries = [library_location]
    150   for lib in kernel_libraries:
--> 151     py_tf.TF_LoadLibrary(lib)
    153 else:
    154   raise OSError(
    155       errno.ENOENT,
    156       'The file or folder to load kernel libraries from does not exist.',
    157       library_location)

NotFoundError: dlopen(/Users/felix/opt/miniconda3/envs/ImageClassification/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow-plugins/libmetal_plugin.dylib, 0x0006): symbol not found in flat namespace '__ZN3tsl8internal10LogMessage16VmoduleActivatedEPKci'
```

**THINGS I HAVE TRIED:
**

Tried what was instructed here - https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/702851

Also here:

[Installing Tensorflow in M1 Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67354277/installing-tensorflow-in-m1-mac)

[Tensorflow on M1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69854533/tensorflow-on-m1)

[What is the proper way to install TensorFlow on Apple M1 in 2022](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72964800/what-is-the-proper-way-to-install-tensorflow-on-apple-m1-in-2022)

Re-installed Miniconda and created everything again. Made sure that TensorFlow deps and TensorFlow macos were both in latest version, then re-tried with both in 2.9.0 version.

- Also tried deleting miniconda completely, and trying everything with miniforge instead, but ran into the same problem.

Overall, I look at all available stack overflow's relevant questions regarding problems with TensorFlow and Mac M1s, but solutions did not solve my requirements and problems.

THINGS I DON´T WANT TO DO:

- Use Miniforge
- Not install tensorflow deps
- Use mamba

I have no idea at this point, I've been trying to make it work for quite a few hours.

I'd appreciate some help!